Undefined reference with requires expression using clang++
I have this test-code which compiles fine with g++ version 13.2 as well as clang++ until version 17. It fails to compile with clang++ version 18.
Is the code valid?
test.cpp:
#include "test.hpp"

#include <optional>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

template<class T>
    requires(!std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
std::optional<T> myFunction(std::string arg) {
    return std::optional<T>{};
}

template std::optional<int> myFunction<int>(std::string arg);

test.hpp:
#pragma once

#include <optional>
#include <string>

template<class T>
std::optional<T> myFunction(std::string arg);

main.cpp:
#include "test.hpp"

#include <optional>

int main()
{
    std::optional<int> foobar = myFunction<int>("foobar");
}


How to reproduce:
#!/bin/sh -x

clang++-18 --version
clang++-18 -std=c++20 -c test.cpp -o test-clang.o
clang++-18 -std=c++20 -c main.cpp -o main-clang.o
clang++-18 main-clang.o test-clang.o -o main-clang

With clang++-18, this produces:
/usr/bin/ld: main-clang.o: in function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x2f): undefined reference to `std::optional<int> myFunction<int>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'
clang++-19: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

nm shows the issue: with clang++-18, the "requires" is part of the name of the exported symbol, whereas it should not as far as I understand.
$ nm --demangle test-clang-17.o | grep -i myFunc
0000000000000000 W std::optional<int> myFunction<int>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)

$ nm --demangle test-clang-18.o | grep -i myFunc
0000000000000000 W std::optional<int> myFunction<int>(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >) requires !(std::is_same_v<int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >)


Not the cause of this problem, but test.cpp needs #include <type_traits> for std::is_sane_v. As written it compiles only by accident.

It seems to be an open issue in the Itanium ABI.

you have two overloads, one constrained and one not, the unconstrained function is used in main.cpp and it's not defined.

@Gene so why does it compile fine with g++ 13 and clang until version 17?

@Étienne -- compiler bugs. You can't have function overloading without distinct signatures.

@Gene OK you're probably right. I couln't find online whether the "requires" was supposed to be part of the function signature or not. However from clang 18's release notes it appears this change is intentional.

I think the requires clause is a part of myFunction's signature, which means it affects the mangled name of your function. Make sure to include that in test.hpp:
template<class T>
  requires(!std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
std::optional<T> myFunction(std::string arg);


I found out this change is documented in clang 18's release notes:

The name mangling rules for function templates has been changed to
take into account the possibility that functions could be overloaded
on their template parameter lists or requires-clauses. This causes
mangled names to change for function templates in the following cases:
When a template parameter in a function template depends on a previous
template parameter, such as template<typename T, T V> void f().
When the function has any constraints, whether from constrained
template parameters or requires-clauses.
When the template parameter list includes a deduced type – either
auto, decltype(auto), or a deduced class template specialization type.
When a template template parameter is given a template template
argument that has a different template parameter list.
This fixes a number of issues where valid programs would be rejected
due to mangling collisions, or would in some cases be silently
miscompiled. Clang will use the old manglings if -fclang-abi-compat=17
or lower is specified. (#48216), (#49884), and (#61273)

